# "PUT" verb trigger update method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

If I defined in the **routes.rb**

```
map.resources :cars
```

Then in my **view**, if I define a form like following;

```
<% form_for :car, @car, :url => cars_url(@car), :html => {:method => :put} do |form|%>

...

<% end %>
```

When I submit the form, I notice that the `update` method inside **cars_controller.rb** is executed.

Is it because of the HTML "**PUT**" verb defined in `:html => {:method => :put}`  in the `form_form` which hints the rails to run **update** method in controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. This is a standard RESTful practice.

The idea is that every car has a unique id. if you "put" to that id - then you are "putting new information in that car object".

Comment: Here's a decent straightforward explanation of the interaction between Rails, REST, CRUD, the HTML verbs, and so on: http://www.sitepoint.com/restful-rails-part-i/